Parameter to use fallback must be a directory, not a file
This line: use OpenSSL::fallback "$FindBin::Bin/external/perl/MODULES.txt"; in Configure in openssl fails when I am running it from a bazel rule.
I am using https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_perl/tree/main to run the Configure script for me. And then a shell script to run the make command. So far though I get stuck on the above error. It only goes away if I remove the line entirely from Configure and not if I modify it.
What is odd to me is that when I do ./Configure it just works as expected. Is there something special about bazel's sandboxing that makes this not work?
load("@rules_perl//perl:perl.bzl", "perl_binary")

perl_binary(
    name = "configure_openssl",
    srcs = ["Configure"],
    data = glob(["**/*.pm"]),
)

sh_binary(
    name = "make",
    srcs = ["run_build.sh"],
    data = [
        "Makefile",
        "config",
        ":configure",
        "@modules",
    ] + glob([
        "include/**/*.h",
        "crypto/**/*.h",
        "ssl/**/*.h",
        "util/**/*",
        "**/build.info",
        "Configurations/*",
        "**/*.in",
        "**/*.pm",
    ]),
)

Also I know that rules_foreign_cc exists but that doesn't work for my purposes because their example for openssl can't even find rm on my system when it runs so that seems more of an uphill battle.
Oh and I get the same error when I use this shell script (only using bazel)
#!/bin/bash
perl Configure && make


Okay I figured it out. Openssl has a module named "fallback" that is looking for a condition not just a directory.
        unless (-e $path
                && ($path =~ m/(?:^|\/)MODULES.txt/ || -d $path)) {
            croak "Parameter to use fallback must be a directory, not a file";
            next;
        }

So what happens is the default path to MODULES.txt no longer exists in bazel because of the way it organizes its runfiles. So the solution is to modify Configure to look at the correct path (something like external/<some_submodule>~/perl/MODULES.txt. I think the error message should be changed to something like "Either the file does not exist, the file does not match a regex, or this is not a directory".
